# How to extract URL parameters with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have somes links like this:

```
mywebsite.com/tutos.php?name=tuto_name#comments
mywebsite.com/tutos.php?name=tuto_name#download
```

My question: how to get the text after the #.

thanks.

Comment: `window.location.hash` - and no jQuery at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following as it not only grabs the `hash` value (without the hash itself (taking the 2nd part (`array[1]` of the `split`)), but also tests the `undefined` case as well which can cause problems in some cases.

```
var hashVal = window.location.hash.split("#")[1];
if( hashVal && hashVal != "undefined" ) {
       //work it 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

`window.location.hash` is a cross browser solution that returns the value (including the hash)

You can remove the hash by doing:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.hash`. It takes with `#` (ie, `#comments`). To remove trialing `#` use `.substring(1)`. Example:

```
var str = window.location.hash.substring(1);
alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following JS function that will do this:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)','i').exec(location.search) || [, ""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null
}
```